# WordPress Responsive Custom Control WP Customizer

Tags: customization, themes, wp-admin, theme-customizer

I'm developing a WordPress theme and I searched for days without finding anything. I have a custom control in WP Customizer and I want that it can save data responsive for desktop, tablet and mobile.

How can I implement it?
Example:

[image]

Comment: What is your screenshot of? That's not a standard WordPress control. Are you sure whatever it is doesn't just have a separate control for each breakpoint, and adds an icon to the label with CSS or something?

Comment: the screenshot is an old custom control found on Github.
I would like to create one myself, I know how to create a custom control, but I don't know how to save and manage data responsive, for desktop, mobile and tablet.
This is only an example  that I want to create.

Comment: What do you imagine needing to do other than just creating a separate control for each breakpoint? Are these controls combined somehow, or involve a toggle of some kind? You mentioned finding it on GitHub, which means you have all the code. Can't you reference that?

Comment: I need to do the same thing with responsive data saving, but on a colour picker... 
from that code, I can't really trace and understand how to make a new one, I have some knowledge of js but I'm not an expert on this language.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Simply I want to create a color picker rgba custom control that saves different data for desktop, tablet and smartphone.